# What are the primitive elements in a polynomial Hopf algebra with primitive indeterminates?

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Asked on math.stackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510606/what-are-the-primitive-elements-in-a-polynomial-hopf-algebra-with-primitive-inde but didn't get response (in fact got a negative vote without any comment), so trying here.

Is it true that in any polynomial Hopf algebra $K[X1,X2,...]$ over a field $K$ with indeterminates primitive, the primitive elements are precisely the linear homogeneous polynomials? (Perhaps with some additional assumptions like characteristic of $K$ is $0$?). If so, could someone kindly give me a reference? A paper I am reading says (without citation) that it is well-known.

Comment: What paper are you reading?

Comment: Assuming you are in the graded situation and, yes, the characteristic is 0, this is standard.  See the famous paper on Hopf algebras from the 1960's by Milnor and Moore.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The paper I am reading is W. Schmitt Hopf algebra methods in graph theory (1995)

Comment: Schmitt does make a standing assumption that the characteristic of $K $ is zero in the paper you are reading. (Though it is somewhat hidden in Section 3.)

Comment: @darij He does make it clear earlier. But just wanted to know the precise result. My bad that I had been reading only the preprint, and should have looked at the published version which has more comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general the claim is not true:

To see why, consider a field $k$ of characteristic $p$ and take the polynomial hopf algebra $k[x]$ (in a single variable). Then $x$ is primitive and so is $x^p$: 
$$
\Delta(x^p)=1\otimes x^p+x^p\otimes 1
$$ 
(because in characteristic $p$: $\binom{p}{i}=0$, for $1\leq i\leq p-1 \ $).

However, in characteristic zero, $k[x]$ is generated by its primitive elements,  which are in fact the homogeneous linear polynomials, in the sense that: $P(k[x])=kx$, as sets,and $k[x]\cong U\big(P(k[x])\big)\cong T(kx)$  as Hopf algebras.
($P(\cdot)$ denotes the Lie algebra of the primitives, $U(\cdot)$ stands for  the universal enveloping algebra of $P(\cdot)$ and $T(.)$ the tensor or symmetric algebra of the one dimensional vector space $kx$).
  Since you are also asking for some reference, the last statement (on characteristic zero) can be found cited explicitly (apart from the celebrated Milnor-Moore paper already cited at the comments to the OP) at the following sources:

- Dascalescu's book, "Hopf algebras. an introduction", p.166, example 8
- Montgomery's book, "Hopf algebras and their actions on rings", p.82, (see the discussion right after the example 5.6.8)
- Abe's book, "Hopf algebras", p.61, example 2.6